# how to write the constructor test code for circle class with radius as parameter

Tags: c#, nunit

How would I write the constructor test code for circle class with radius as parameter

this is the production code:

```
using MyGeometry.Abstract;
using MyGeometry.Interface;

namespace MyGeometry.RealShapes
{
    public class Circle : Shape, IFlatShape
    {
        public Circle(int radius)
        {
            Length = radius;
        }

        public double CalculateArea()
        {
            return 3.14*Length*Length;
        }

        public double CalculatePerimeter()
        {
            return 2*3.14*Length;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the test case:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MyGeometry.RealShapes;

namespace ShapeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CircleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CircleConstructorTest()
        {
           //what should be written here???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test? Do you want to test if you can instantiate an instance of the Circle?

Comment: What you are trying to test through constructor..

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're trying to test.  If you're trying to test that your constructor throws an exception if you give it bad input, you could write something similar to:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldThrowExceptionIfArgumentIsOutOfRange()
{
    try 
    {
        new Circle(-1);
        Assert.Fail("Constructor did not throw exception");
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

Though this is only useful if you're looking to test behavior within the constructor alone.  If you want to test code relating to the methods of the class, you would write methods to test those, providing inputs and examining the results of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matthew said you can test if radius argument *is greater than 0*

```
namespace ShapeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CircleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
        public void RadiusIsGreaterThanZero()
        {
           Circle c = new Circle(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want your constructor *to pass this test* you should modify your **Circle class** to:

```
using MyGeometry.Abstract;
using MyGeometry.Interface;

namespace MyGeometry.RealShapes
{
    public class Circle : Shape, IFlatShape
    {
        public Circle(int radius)
        {
            if(radius > 0)
                Length = radius;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Radius must be greater than zero");
        }

        ......
    }
}
```